# php mysql UPDATE command wont update

Tags: php, html, mysql

All the data is loaded into a table, each row as a button. Once the button has been pressed, the row has to be updated. But when I click on the button, nothing happens. The text box on the rows return to its original value... It is really starting to cheese me off

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

    <head>
        <title>Edit Students</title>
    </head>

<?php

            $user = 'root';     //Database username ("Root for xampp")
            $pass = '';             //Database password ("empty for exampp")
            $db = 'dragondrivingschooldb';      //Name of database

            $con = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("Unable to connect");  //Create new data connection ('name of host/server', user, password, database name)

            if (isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])) {   //Once Update button pressed perform this code

                $updatequery = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE booking SET FirstName='$_POST[txtfirstname]' WHERE BookingID='$_POST[txtid]' "); //excute UpDate Query

            };  

            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM booking"); //Select All from Booking

        //Create Headers for table

    echo "<table border='1'>                
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Booking ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>

    </tr>";

    //Show Edit Form///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {    //Run sql code till there are no more rows to import 

    echo "<form action=EditStudent.php method=post>";    //Run update code at top of this page

    //Populate table with query (sql)

    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> <input name=update type=submit value=update /> </td>";           //once press update row this button is apart of
        echo "<td> <input type=text value=" . $row['BookingID'] . " name=txtid /> </td>";
        echo "<td> <input type=text value=" . $row['FirstName'] . " name=txtfirstname /> </td>";

    echo "</tr>";
    }


    echo "</table>";

    echo "</form>";

    mysqli_close($con);     //Close connection

    ?>


</html>
```

Comment: Also I am aware this code is open to SQL injection, once the UPDATE function works, I shall then move onto improve the security (Bad $_POST)

Comment: You need to look up how to catch the error mysqli_query might be throwing, do you even know if you've successfully connected to the database?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` if you're not already doing so.

Comment: The SELECT * FROM booking works.... So there is a connection...

Comment: added the error reporting, nothing is showing up

Comment: One thing I noticed is this `if (isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])) {` your UPDATE is dependant on that conditional statement, which I'm under the impression you're wanting to use it in conjunction with `<input name=update type=submit value=update />` If so, then you'll need to change that to `<input name='btnUpdate' type='submit' value='update' />` while adding quotes for it. You really should add quotes inside `<form action=EditStudent.php method=post>` etc. that's known to cause havoc at times.

Comment: What's being asked? What have you tried? Sounds like a "debug my code" question.

Comment: I click on the button to update, all it is doing is returning the value of my text boxes back to its original value.... is there another way to call the update query when the button is pressed?

Comment: I tried chaning the name of the button and it still not working :-/

Comment: have you checked if isset($_POST['btnUpdate']) is even returning true..........? The horrific quality of the answers below is testament to the fact this question should be closed.

Comment: You should also quote `name=txtfirstname` and the other(s) --- `name='txtfirstname'`

Comment: after putting quotes around my text, it is actually showing me an error message....  Undefined index: txtfirstname... &  Undefined index: txtid in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that BookingID it is an integer, so your update line need to be:

```
$updatequery = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE booking SET FirstName='" . $_POST['txtfirstname'] . "' WHERE BookingID=" . $_POST['txtid'] . ""); //excute UpDate Query
```

**EDIT:**
I tested your script and the problem was that you closed the form outside the while loop. Now its working

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<head>
    <title>Edit Students</title>
</head>

<?php

        $user = 'root';     //Database username ("Root for xampp")
        $pass = '';             //Database password ("empty for exampp")
        $db = 'all_tests';      //Name of database

        $con = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("Unable to connect");         //Create new data connection ('name of host/server', user, password, database name)

        if (isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])) {   //Once Update button pressed perform this  code

            $updatequery = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE test_1 SET FirstName='" . $_POST['txtfirstname'] . "' WHERE BookingID='" . $_POST['txtid'] . "'"); //excute UpDate Query

        };  

        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *FROM test_1"); //Select All from Booking

    //Create Headers for table

echo "<table border='1'>                
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Booking ID</th>
    <th>First Name</th>

</tr>";

//Show Edit Form///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {    //Run sql code till there are no more rows to import 

echo "<form method=post>";    //Run update code at top of this page

//Populate table with query (sql)

echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> <input name='btnUpdate' type='submit' value='update' /> </td>";           //once press update row this button is apart of
    echo "<td> <input type='text' value=" . $row['BookingID'] . " name='txtid' /> </td>";
    echo "<td> <input type='text' value=" . $row['FirstName'] . " name='txtfirstname' /> </td>";

echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
}


echo "</table>";



mysqli_close($con);     //Close connection

?>
```

Comment: Still returning the text box to the original value

Comment: it works.... thank you, you're a life saver, cant believe I wasted 2 days on this one function argh... Thanks

Comment: i`m glad I helped, take care and keep going!

Answer (score -1):

at first check that $_POST[txtid] has value or not. and be sure that field name is correct or incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

There are no input field in your html that has name btnUpdate. What I can see its name is update. Therefore your row:

```
if (isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])) {
```

would never be true