# php mysql login form

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I am trying to build a quick and dirty login form, but I keep on getting a php error "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in" 
I tried looking around but nothing seems to help or work....

```
<?php

    $user = 'root';     //Database username ("Root for xampp")
    $pass = '';             //Database password ("empty for exampp")
    $db = 'dragondrivingschooldb';      //Name of database

    $con = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("Unable to connect");  //Create new data connection ('name of host/server', user, password, database name)

    if(isset($_POST['txtusername'])) 
    {

    $username = $_POST['txtusername'];
    $password = $_POST['txtpassword'];

    $SQL = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=' " . $username ." ' AND password= ' " . $password . " ' LIMIT 1 ");

    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($SQL);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
       echo "Hello World";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "no";
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>


  <!DOCTYPE html>
     <form method="post" action="Login.php">
        username: <input type="text" name="txtusername"><br>
        password: <input type="text" name="txtpassword"> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" >
    </form> 
</html>
```

Comment: Use `mysqli_num_rows($SQL)` instead, read the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php#example-1821 - you have to pass the result of the query. It won't accept an array. Either use that code or `count($result)`.

Comment: This means that your SQL query returned nothing.

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs. This isn't rhum & coke.

Comment: You had working code in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703433/php-mysql-update-command-wont-update). What's wrong now (*I know the why*) and why did you change something that wasn't broken? Stay with one MySQL API and go with that. We can't always keep on tutoring you or fixing mistakes that could have been avoided. In other words; when you see `mysqli_` and `mysql_` those do **not** work together. Either make all your functions `mysqli_` or `mysql_` --- the latter is not the preferred API, btw.

Comment: If one doesn't already exist, I'm tempted to write a script that will detect any instances of `mysql_` and replace them with `mysqli_` and just pop that into an answer whenever I see questions like these, when mixing APIs. The OP could then just pop that into their code.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use the mysql_num_rows()-function on the result ARRAY(!). mysql_num_rows needs the sql-resource and not the php-array which is returned by mysqli_fetch_array.

So use

```
if(count($result)===1) {...}
```

or (preferably)

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($SQL) === 1) { ... }
```

and use mysql or mysqli - but don't mix both.

By the way: Make sure to protect the query against injection as you directly use the user-input in your query.